# Is it possible to access hardware performance counter using webassembly?

Tags: hpc, webassembly

I want to monitor HPC events, like cache events, using Webassembly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

WebAssembly only has access to memory and compute, it doesn’t have any direct access to system, web or other APIs. In order to perform IO from a WebAssembly module, you must import / export functions from the host environment.

There are various proposals underway to standardise this interface, but I’m not aware of any that supply HPC events. You’re going to have to do this yourself.